# SPARQL "Different Than"

Tags: sparql, rdf, graph-databases

### Background

I have a graph database where nodes represent individual people and the edges are predicates *hasMother* and *hasFather*. I'd like to identify all of the nodes that share a mother, but *don't* share the same father.

### Attempt

There are a few SPARQL terms that immediately pop into my mind when thinking about this problem. Namely `Filter`, `!=` and `NOT EXISTS`.

I first set out and defined some sets...

Let M be the set of all winiks that have mother id, mother_id.

Let F be the set of all winiks that have father id, father_id.

The following query returns a qraph of M ∩ F.

```
PREFIX ex: <https://ex.com#>
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>

CONSTRUCT WHERE {
    ?winik_id ex:hasMother ?mother_id.
    ?winik_id ex:hasFather ?father_id.
}
```

My hiccup is writing the exclusion part (its actually hard for me to verbalize the exact part I'm stuck on)-specifically how to deal with how general the query is (across all identifiers).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should return pairs of people that have the same mother but different father.

```
SELECT ?p1 ?p2 WHERE {
?p1 ex:hasMother ?m .
?p1 ex:hasFather ?f .
?p2 ex:hasMother ?m .
?p2 ex:hasFather ?f2 .
FILTER (?f != ?f2)
```